# Which is the best way to write data buf to file

Tags: c, file-io

Which is the best way to write data buf to file?

```
char buf[1024];
FILE *fp = fopen("test", "a+");
```

1. `fwrite(buf, 1, 1024, fp);`
2. `fwrite(buf, 1024, 1, fp);`
3. `for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) fwrite(buf, 1, 1, fp);`
4. or another higher performance way?

Comment: i mean "highest performance"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is slow; probably very slow.  In all probability, you'd do better with `putc()` than `fwrite()` in the body of the loop.

The difference between the first two options is the return value.  The first outputs 1024 single bytes, and will return 1024 if completely successful, or some smaller number if it fails.  The second outputs a single unit of 1024 bytes; it will return 1 if it writes them all, but 0 if it fails to write them all.  Whether that matters depends on what you might do in event of a short write.  Other than the return value, the two are equivalent.

There isn't an alternative higher-performance way, at least while you stick with file streams.  Switching to file descriptors opens up more options, but a single `write` call for the data is probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 will be the same...
but, I'd do 1, but like :-

```
fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), 1024, fp);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so just use 1 for brevity.

Comment: One and two are different in the return value.